# Llamar a método automáticamente

Tags: java

Supongamos q tengo un servicio rest

```
http://localhost:8080/test/api/check
```

Y quiero que este servicio se llame una vez al día, pero quien lo llame sea la misma aplicación, es posible?

NOTA: no puedo usar un cron

Comment: Que sistema operativo tiene el servidor? linux?

Comment: pre-producción linux, producción windows

Comment: Es que lo que quieres yo diría que no es posible. Si es windows, yo lo que haría sería usar una tarea programada que hiciera la llamada al servicio, similar al cron de linux

Comment: Qué tal Quartz (http://quartz-scheduler.org)?
Es un scheduler en Java, puede sustituir a cron

Comment: Si es la misma aplicación siempre es posible programar la tarea para que se ejecute a cierta hora del día, algo similar a lo que es setInterval en javascript

Comment: ¿Por qué no puedes usar un cron? Y quizás aún más preocupante, ¿por qué tu ambiente de producción difiere tanto del ambiente de pre producción?

Comment: cosas del cliente :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es la misma aplicación, puedes crear una tarea usando Quartz o directamente usando Spring:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?")
public void scheduledMethod() {

    // tarea a realizar
}
```

Para que esto funciones necesitas añadir a la configuración de Spring la anotación correspondiente:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringConfig {
    ...
}
```

o si la configuracìón va por XML:

```
<task:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 01 * * ?") si lo quiero todos los dias a la 1am no?

Comment: @sirdaiz Correcto, no estoy seguro del cero a la izquierda pero por lo demás es así.

Answer (score 0):

Particularmente y por experiencia yo no llamaría es usar alguna librería de scheduler en java. Sobretodo al hacer esto debes poner especial cuidado en no hacer una petición http. No es necesario si realizas un diseño diseño para poder tener llamar al mismo "comando" desde distintos endpoint. Un ejemplo vale mas que mil palabras:

```
public class Comando{
    public String hacerAlgo(){
        //Haz las operaciones que necesites
    }
}
```

El endpoint rest, no he usado las anotaciones de Spring porque no se si lo utilizas.

```
    @Path("/test/api/check")
    public class EndPoint1{

        private Comando comando;

        @Get
        public String hacerAlgo(){
            //Aquí el codigo para transformar los parametros y validarlos si fuera necesario

            String response = comando. hacerAlgo();

            //Aqui el codigo para transformar la respuesta si fuera necesario
        }
    }
```

La creación del quartz, si usas Spring lo tienes super fácil con [las indicaciones de @Pablo Lozano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/101341/16943). Como he supuesto que no lo usas te pongo un ejemplo usando Quartz [Doc quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example3.html) Deberás hacer una llamada al método init al arrancar la aplicación, como no tengo información de tu sistema no puedo darte detalles.

```
    public class TriggerInit{

        public String init(){

          JobDetail job = newJob(Comando.class)
             .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
                  .build();

          // Aqui tienes como hacer un triger
          Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
              .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
              .startNow()
              .withSchedule(cronSchedule("15 0/2 * * * ?"))
              .build();

          // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
          scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
    }
```

También he supuesto por simplicidad que no necesitas parámetros.