# ¿Trigger en java?

Tags: java, trigger

Tengo una curiosidad, podria hacer algun tipo de trigger en java? Por ejemplo quisiera que cada semana mi aplicacion me enviara un correo, por decir algo con todas la ventas realizadas la semana anterior, por que podria estar revisando la fecha con un while pero no creo que sea lo mas optimo.

Comment: Existen varios frameworks que te permiten hacerlo, quizá el más famoso sea Quartz. Si estamos hablando de una aplicación J2EE con Spring, puedes [usar sus anotaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101338/llamar-a-m%C3%A9todo-autom%C3%A1ticamente/101341#101341)

Comment: Y tendría que usar por fuerza Spring? Sí, la aplicación es web pero no uso ningún framework aunque si están separada por capas (paquetes: modelo, 
 dao, controlador).

Comment: Quartz funciona por sí solo, no necesitas Spring ni otro framework. Por otro lado, podrías tener un demonio, tal como indica abrahamhs en su respuesta. Otra forma de implementarlo, usando Java puro, es mediante un [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Comment: Ah bueno, perfecto. Gracias por la info! Investigare sobre esos temas. Pura vida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

busca la documentación de quartz, este trabaja bajo hilos y en determinado momento, según la configuración te da un reporte, un mensaje, etc, si deseas ver como funciona revisa un ejemplo sencillo de quartz,

en esta dirección url, encuentras un ejemplo donde te saluda cada 5 segundos, claramente tu puedes configurar el tiempo que desees

http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-2-scheduler-tutorial/

espero te sirva y quedo pendiente.

Comment: Excelente! Gracias por la info.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres hacer se llama demonio, no trigger. En un demonio programas lo que quieres hacer (en este caso enviar un correo con un reporte) y para hacer que se ejecute periodicamente lo registras como tarea programada en windows o lo agregas al crontab en cualquier unix como linux o solaris.

Comment: Gracias era la orientación que necesitaba.

Comment: Recuerda votar por la respuesta que mas te ayudo.